# Decoding G.729 using FFMPEG from RTP stream (PCAP)

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, ip, rtp, pcap

I have pcap file that contains RTP data which in turn is audio for G.729 codec. Is there a way to decode this stream by pushing it into FFMPEG? This would probably mean I have to extract the RTP payload data from the PCAP file and then somehow pass it to FFMPEG.

Any guidelines and pointers are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer doesn't require `ffmpeg`, but I assume you dont really care how the audio is extracted... check out [How to Decode G729](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecodeG729) on the wireshark wiki...

1. In Wireshark, use menu "Statistics -> RTP -> Show All Streams". Select the desired stream and press "Analyze".
2. In the next dialog screen, press "Save Payload...". Save options are `Format = .raw` and `Channel = forward`. Name file `my_input.raw`.
3. Convert the `.raw` file to `.pcm` format using the `Open G.729` decoder. Syntax: `va_g729_decoder.exe my_input.raw my_output.pcm`. Or for Linux: `wine va_g729_decoder.exe my_input.raw my_output.pcm`.
4. The `.pcm` file contains 16-bit linear PCM samples at 8000 Hz. Note that each sample is in Little-Endian format. To convert to `.au` format, all you need to do is prepend the 24-byte au header, and convert each PCM sample to network byte order (or Big-Endian). The following `perl` script will do the trick.

USAGE: `perl pcm2au.pl [my_inputFile] [my_outputFile]`

```perl
$usage = "Usage: 'perl $0 [Source PCM File] [Destination AU File]' ";

$my_inputFile = shift or die $usage;
$my_outputFile = shift or die $usage;

open(INPUTFILE, "$my_inputFile") or die "Unable to open file: $!\n";
binmode INPUTFILE;

open(OUTPUTFILE, "> $my_outputFile") or die "Unable to open file: $!\n";
binmode OUTPUTFILE;

###################################
# Write the AU header
###################################

print OUTPUTFILE  ".snd";

$foo = pack("CCCC", 0,0,0,24);
print OUTPUTFILE  $foo;

$foo = pack("CCCC", 0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff);
print OUTPUTFILE  $foo;

$foo = pack("CCCC", 0,0,0,3);
print OUTPUTFILE  $foo;

$foo = pack("CCCC", 0,0,0x1f,0x40);
print OUTPUTFILE  $foo;

$foo = pack("CCCC", 0,0,0,1);
print OUTPUTFILE  $foo;

#############################
# swap the PCM samples
#############################

while (read(INPUTFILE, $inWord, 2) == 2) {

    @bytes   = unpack('CC', $inWord);
    $outWord = pack('CC', $bytes[1], $bytes[0]);
    print OUTPUTFILE  $outWord;
}

close(OUTPUTFILE);
close(INPUTFILE);
```

Comment: Checking this out as I type :)

Comment: Well this gives me an idea on how to go forward. Probably requires me to do some extra coding to make it into a program. Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The steps that you can use are:

1. extract the RTP/RTCP packets: with a tool like rtpbreak: http://dallachiesa.com/code/rtpbreak/
2. generate (with and editor) a sdp file to be passed at ffmpeg or mplayer or vlan
3. launch ffmpeg (or mplayer or vlan) with SDP file
4. stream RTP/RTCP packets at ffmpeg with rtpplay: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/irt/software/rtptools/

But if your goal is "only" the pcap-audio decoding (with RTP G729 codec) then you can use videosnaf or xplico

Answer (score 1):

va_g729_decoder.exe  only works for win32.What about 64bit windows ?